# Partial specialization of a nested class

Tags: c++, templates

How to partially specialize nest**ed** class without partially specializing the nest**ing** class?

Implementation of `class C` is the same for all `N`.

Implementation of `C::iterator` is special for `N=1`.

```
template<class T, int N>
class C
{
    class iterator;
    ...
};

template<class T, int N>
class C<T, N>::iterator
{
    ...
};

// Partial specialization doesn't compile:
template<class T>
class C<T, 1>::iterator
{
    ...
};
```

I can partially specialize `class C` for `N=1`, but that's a lot of code duplication...

Comment: In your actual code, is `iterator` inside `C` a non-template like it is here?  If so, that's your problem.  `iterator` needs to be template in order to specialize it.

Comment: You want to partially specialize iterator, but iterator is something that is not template. It does not make much sense to partially specialize things that are not templates. Specializing C makes sense as it is template.

Comment: So you are attempting to provide a different definition of `iterator` depending on the value of the non-type template parameter `N`?

Comment: @WBuck
Yes, and as the guys above say, `iterator` itself if not a templated class. So I see where the error comes from. Nevertheless, it's annoying to duplicate `class C` code for `N=1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to specialize whole class then just move the iterator out of class and make it template:

```
template<class T, int N>
class C_iterator
{
    ...
};
```

If needed make your specializations:

```
template<class T>
class C_iterator<T, 1>
{
    ...
};
```

Then use it in your class as iterator, if needed befriend it:

```
template<class T, int N>
class C
{
    using iterator = C_iterator<T, N>;
    friend iterator;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Like it, nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that:

```cpp
template<class T>
class C<T, 1>::iterator {
    // ...
}
```

Attempts to be the definition for a member class `iterator` on a partial specialisation for `C`, where no such partial specialisation exists. The exact same issue would happen if you tried this with a non-static data member, a member function, or a member template: C++ does not allow partial specialisations where only the outer class is partially specialised.

For example, this compiles:

```cpp
template<class T, int N>
class C {
    class iterator;  // (A)
};

template<class T>
class C<T, 1> {
    class iterator;  // (B)
};

template<class T, int N>
class C<T, N>::iterator {};  // Definition for entity declared at (A)

template<class T>
class C<T, 1>::iterator {};  // Definition for entity declared at (B)  *not a partial template specialisation
```

Whereas without the partial specialisation near (B), there is nothing for the second definition to define. As a general rule of thumb, a partial specialisation can only refer to the innermost entity, so it must be a template.

(Note this has nothing to do with what kind of entity `iterator` is: The same issue would have happened if `iterator` was a template class and you try to partially specialise it based on `N=1`)

---

So the simplest answer is: you can't do exactly what you want to do.

The simplest solution is what Öö Tiib's answer is: Lift the class out and make `iterator` a member type alias.

For fun, you could make `iterator` a template class so you can partially specialise it. You still can't partially specialise the outer class only, so I use a constraint to emulate it:

```cpp
template<class T, int N>
class C
{
    template<std::nullptr_t = nullptr>
    class iterator;
};

template<class T, int N>
template<std::nullptr_t>
class C<T, N>::iterator
{
};

template<class T, int N>
template<std::nullptr_t dummy> requires (N==1)
class C<T, N>::iterator<dummy>
{
};

// The first is a primary definition, the second a partial specialisation
// (Could have also made them both partial specialisations, with the first `requires (N!=1)`)
```

Comment: Thank you @Artyer for detailed explanation. Choose Öö Tiib's as a main answer. Giving you +1

Answer (score 0):

By re declare the iterator class, You can get the same result.

```
template<class T, int N>
class C
{
    class iterator {};
};

template<class T>
class C<T, 1>
{
    class iterator {};
};
```

It should be separated from the common working part of the class. (unless you want to rewrite it)

```
template<class T>
class CWork
{
};

template<class T, int N>
class C : public CWork<T>
{
    class iterator {};
};

template<class T>
class C<T, 1> : public CWorkDefine
{
    class iterator {};
};
```